# Java: bind windows key

Tags: java

I'm trying to bind the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key using Java and I'm failing.
I can bind the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with something else.

But, if I want to use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, I can't get it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me I used following constant from KeyEvent class.

```
/**
 * Constant for the Microsoft Windows "Windows" key.
 * It is used for both the left and right version of the key.  
 * @see #getKeyLocation()
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static final int VK_WINDOWS                  = 0x020C;
```

I implement my KeyListener method in following way and it worked (I am using ubuntu 10):

```
    // Invoked when a key has been pressed.
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Returns the integer code for the key on the keyboard and if
        // keyCode is equal to VK_WINDOWS)...
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) {
            // ...call the doIT method.
            doIT();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the Windows key is usually mapped to the meta key, so try `Event.META_MASK`.

Comment: Ubuntu maps it to "Super". Opensuse maps it to "Meta". You can use xmodmap to change that.