# Java Robot class, windows key is not working on linux

Tags: java

Out of curiosity, I wanted to press the Windows key + t. In my current Linux configuration that would open my file manager, but the windows key is not registering at all. I've tried a bunch of things, like using the ctrl + alt key events but they register correctly and they did not simulate a windows key press (this is because of an answer I found to a similar question). I have also tried it with the keycode 524 to no avail. the t is still shown as being pressed.

```
        Robot robo = new Robot();

        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

can anyone tell me exactly what I'm missing?

Comment: Needless to say, I know I can just run my file manager with Runtime, I just don't get why this key is being so difficult.

Comment: This thread - [java bind windows key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456300/java-bind-windows-key) looks like it has an answer ...